# Using defaultdict with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, defaultdict

Just experimenting and learning, and I know how to create a shared dictionary that can be accessed with multiple proceses but I'm not sure how to keep the dict synced. `defaultdict`, I believe, illustrates the problem I'm having.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process

#test without multiprocessing
s = 'mississippi'
d = defaultdict(int)
for k in s:
    d[k] += 1

print d.items() # Success! result: [('i', 4), ('p', 2), ('s', 4), ('m', 1)]
print '*'*10, ' with multiprocessing ', '*'*10

def test(k, multi_dict):
    multi_dict[k] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    mgr = Manager()
    multi_d = mgr.dict()
    for k in s:
        pool.apply_async(test, (k, multi_d))

    # Mark pool as closed -- no more tasks can be added.
    pool.close()

    # Wait for tasks to exit
    pool.join()

    # Output results
    print multi_d.items()  #FAIL

print '*'*10, ' with multiprocessing and process module like on python site example', '*'*10
def test2(k, multi_dict2):
    multi_dict2[k] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    multi_d2 = manager.dict()
    for k in s:
        p = Process(target=test2, args=(k, multi_d2))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print multi_d2 #FAIL
```

The first result works(because its not using `multiprocessing`), but I'm having problems getting it to work with `multiprocessing`.  I'm not sure how to solve it but I think there might be due to it not being synced(and joining the results later) or maybe because within `multiprocessing` I cannot figure how to set `defaultdict(int)` to the dictionary.

Any help or suggestions on how to get this to work would be great!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can subclass `BaseManager` and register additional types for sharing. You need to provide a suitable proxy type in cases where the default `AutoProxy`-generated type does not work. For `defaultdict`, if you only need to access the attributes that are already present in `dict`, you can use `DictProxy`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, DictProxy
from collections import defaultdict

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('defaultdict', defaultdict, DictProxy)

def test(k, multi_dict):
    multi_dict[k] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    mgr = MyManager()
    mgr.start()
    multi_d = mgr.defaultdict(int)
    for k in 'mississippi':
        pool.apply_async(test, (k, multi_d))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print multi_d.items()
```

Comment: Wow, it worked, thank you.  I don't really understand your modifications,  What is the purpose of class MyManager(BaseManager)?

Comment: @Lostsoul It is [the documented way](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) to add support for sharing other types than what Manager supports.

Comment: @JanneKarila Do you know where I could find a list of all the proxytypes?

Comment: @Grr Look into [the source code of `managers.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py)

Comment: surprised that these collections are not supported by the original manager class, but thanks a lot for letting us know that it's possible!

Comment: @Janne Karila Would you know [how to use **nested** defaultdict with multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685275/how-to-use-nested-defaultdict-with-multiprocessing)

Comment: @Janne Karila Do you have a solution how to register a defaultdict(list) ?

Comment: Getting ```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 553, in _create
    assert self._state.value == State.STARTED, 'server not yet started'
AssertionError: server not yet started```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have an additional question: Can I use ` multi_d = mgr.defaultdict(dict) ` ? the given parameter `dict` will generate a new dict object, but the object is not multiple processing shared? Do I need to use `multi_d = mgr.defaultdict(mgr.dict)` instead?

Comment: @Wotchin Changes in the inner `dict`s would not be propagated to other processes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the `Manager` class seems to supply only a fixed number of predefined data structures which can be shared among processes, and `defaultdict` is not among them. If you really just need that one `defaultdict`, the easiest solution would be to implement the defaulting behavior on your own:

```
def test(k, multi_dict):
    if k not in multi_dict:
        multi_dict[k] = 0
    multi_dict[k] += 1
```